# Rewrite a Vim function to a one-line map

Tags: vim, configuration

[This](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/commit/34844f2787400bdca28ec6214313ce6a33dde8f7) works:

```
nmap <silent> <S-t> :call InventTab()<CR>
function InventTab()
    set expandtab!
    if &expandtab
        retab
        echo 'spaces'
    else
        retab!
        echo 'tabs'
    endif
endfunction
```

I've tried to change it to a one-liner:

```
nmap <silent> <S-t> :set expandtab!<CR>:if &expandtab<CR>:retab<CR>:echo 'spaces'<CR>:else<CR>:retab!<CR>:echo 'tabs'<CR>:endif<CR>
```

The problem now is that it it insists on printing "Press ENTER or type command to continue" afterwards. If I add another `<CR>` it doesn't do that anymore, but then the `echo` output is cleared.

How should I write this to make sure I see the output but no extra stuff?

[Result](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/e16cc3952800e9c625ea014e9febd57707809f84/.vimrc#L47) (see the [accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/18037/rewrite-a-vim-function-to-a-one-line-map/18046#18046) for details):

```
nmap <silent> <S-t> :set expandtab! ^V| if &expandtab ^V| retab ^V| echo 'spaces' ^V| else ^V| retab! ^V| echo 'tabs' ^V| endif<CR>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does replacing the `<CR>`'s you have between commands with `^V|` (where `^V` is a literal `^V` inserted by typing <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd>) work?

Comment: It still runs, but no `echo` output...

Comment: Strange it works for me when I have `nmap <silent> <S-t> :set expandtab! ^V| if &expandtab ^V| retab ^V| echo 'spaces' ^V| else ^V| retab! ^V| echo 'tabs' ^V| endif<CR>`.  Maybe try it without any plugins loaded and see if anything changes?

Comment: That works for me as well - I understood "between commands" as "between `retab` and `echo`". Excellent!